# git create 2 branches from 2 different repos without "unrelated history" error

Tags: git, github

I have a repo (`repo1`) where I have 2 branches, `app-dev` and `app-prod`. I have created a second repo (`repo2`) with the branches `develop` and `release/v1.0.0`.

Now I want the `develop` branch to have the contents of the `app-dev` branch and the `release/v1.0.0` branch to have the contents of the `app-prod` branch in `repo2` and I also want the `release/v1.0.0` branch to be mergeable back into the `develop` branch.

Right now when I do the merging part, it fails with an error saying `"fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories"`

Please suggest an optimal way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you *have to* merge those branches (which are both "orphan": no common history), you can use the [`--allow-unrelated-histories`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---allow-unrelated-histories) option.

> This option can be used to override this safety when merging histories of two projects that started their lives independently